# Swift: How do I invalidate all running timers?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am currently working on a project were other third party developers can add functionalities to an iOS App. Therefore I don't want them to start timers and do something later when there object instances already got deleted. So is there a way to invalidate all running timers or certain running timers without a reference to them. If not is there any other way that I can enable timer functionality to the devs but prevent them from using them outside their "area". Should I overwrite timer or any better suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You probably don't need to worry about it; It is the other developer's responsibility to clean up their stuff, and if they haven't invalidated the timer then the object won't be released since the timer will be holding a strong reference; you may get a memory leak but you won't get a reference to a deleted object

Comment: I would try offer timer functionality via the API so that you can keep track of the active timers yourself and invalidate them when you delete the objects. Of course it wont hinder developers from creating timers on their own but now they have a preferred option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `Timer` and have a shared instance which has stores all the timers currently in use. You have to use this `CustomTimer` instead of `Timer` whenever you need a timer.

```
class CustomTimer: Timer {

    static var sharedTimers: [CustomTimer] = []

    static func invalidateAllTimers() {
        for timer in CustomTimer.sharedTimers {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }

    // Use appropriate initializer and super calls.
    init() {
        CustomTimer.sharedTimers.append(self)
    }

    deinit {
        CustomTimer.sharedTimers.removeAll { (timer) -> Bool in
            return timer === self
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can invalidate all the timers by using the `invalidateAllTimers` method.

```
CustomTimer.invalidateAllTimers()
```

Comment: @vadian Isn't that what i am doing in init by appending self to the array?

Comment: And this will only work if the other developers use your `CustomTimer` class; if they just use an ordinary `Timer` then there is no way to keep track.

Comment: @Paulw11, yes that is my solution. Using a custom timer.

Comment: If you can't trust the other developers to manage their timer instances how can you trust them to use the custom timer?

Comment: and you cannot overwrite the original Timer and NSTimer right, or can you?

Comment: @SirJoe i couldn't find a way to access the default initializer while extending `Timer`. You could use `convenience` intializer in an extension and do the same thing i did here. But then again your developers would need to use that particular `convenience` initializer for it work like intended.

Comment: I guess I am gonna write my own timer class and search for Timer or NSTimer usage in the  3rd party devs code

Comment: sure! But please upvote my comment where I say what I will do exactly since your answer is only a part of the answer

Comment: I get the error `'self' used before 'super.init' call` Do you know what init I can call to make this work? Because super.init() by itself didn't work. I'm working alone on something alone so I don't have to worry about other people using my CustomCallout task

Comment: I get the error `'self' used before 'super.init' call` Do you know what init I can call to make this work? Because super.init() by itself didn't work. I'm working alone on something alone so I don't have to worry about other people using my CustomCallout Class. The only time I"m using timer is `Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(myFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

Comment: @Jacob call the respective `super.init` method before the code i have written in my `init`

Comment: I'm wondering what the init is. Not when to run it, because `super.init()` doesn't work. Is there a default init that would work?

Comment: @Jacob make it a `convenience init`, then call `self.init` inside it.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Got error **'self' used before 'super.init' call** Can you please help me I want to use in this https://stackoverflow.com/q/55789718/10150796 to invalidate all running timers.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani you have to use the proper init.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Can't Understand what exactly you want to say I just Copy this class and past in my project and got this error. my code is in swift 5.
**'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer**

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani why did you copy paste? This is not a project. This is an answer. Read the comment in the answer.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I know very well this is not a project but if you make a class for common use so I think you know that why getting this error. Not only me but you can see the previous comments so if possible you need to check and update it.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I did not make a class. It is an example to demonstrate the logic behind the answer. It is really so simple. Just use a valid `init` of `Timer` class or a `convenience init`. if you read the comments, you'll notice that i have already explained it.

Comment: From Apple's doc on Timer: 
Subclassing Notes
Do not subclass Timer.