# Multiple CollectionView inside the UITableView Cell ( Autoscroll ) issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, autoscroll

I have Multiple `CollectionView` Inside the `TableView` and want to implement autoscrolling individually according to data count in each `CollectionView`

> This code is working fine for single CollectionView

**My `UITableViewCell` code is Here**

```
class PromotionalOfferCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var collVwPromotionalOffer: UICollectionView!

    var x = 1
    var scroll_timer : Timer?

    var data_obj = [PromotionalOfferData]() {
        didSet {
            print(data_obj)
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if collVwPromotionalOffer != nil{
            self.collVwPromotionalOffer.dataSource = self
            self.collVwPromotionalOffer.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func setTimer() {
        scroll_timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func autoScroll() {
        if self.x < self.data_obj.count {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: x, section: 0)
            self.collVwPromotionalOffer.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
            self.x = self.x + 1

        } else {
            self.x = 0
            self.collVwPromotionalOffer.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        }
    }

}

// CollectionView Delegate & DataSource

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if data_obj.count > 0{
            return data_obj.count
        }
        return 0
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as? ImageCell

    cell?.imgView.sd_setImage(with:URL(string: data_obj[indexPath.row].image!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "cod_logo"), options: [.highPriority]) { (image, error, cashtype, url) in }

    return cell!
}
```

`UITableView` Delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableViewItems.count > 0{
        return self.tableViewItems.count
    }
    return 0
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let Promotional_Item = tableViewItems[indexPath.row] as? [PromotionalOfferData]{

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PromotionalOfferCell", for: indexPath) as! PromotionalOfferCell

            cell.data_obj = Promotional_Item
            cell.collVwPromotionalOffer.reloadData()

            if cell.scroll_timer != nil {
                cell.scroll_timer!.invalidate()
                cell.scroll_timer = nil
            }

            if Promotional_Item.count > 1{
                cell.setTimer()
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
```

**My Output is Like this**

[image]

> The issue is that I print in Log and realize that the timer is called
>   more than one time for each `CollectionView`
>
> Due to this the memory size of Application is Continues increase and I
>   already `invalidate` the timer

Can someone tell me where I am Wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: the tableviewcell will be reused. I'd be good to handle in cellWillApprear and disappear I think

Comment: There seems to be no issue with the code that you have posted. Can you show `UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource` as well?

Comment: @Adeel Also no any issue in delegate because it may only load the image. even that I added in Question.

Comment: `awakeFromNib` is called only once so there's no chance of multiple instantiation of the timer. Can you show the `UITableViewDataSource` where you are dequeueing the `PromotionalOfferCell` and setting the `data_obj` array?

Comment: @Adeel As you say add UITableViewDataSource in my question

Comment: Even your `UITableViewDataSource` is correct. Are you sure the tableView or the collectionView or the timer is the is reason behind excessive memory usage? have tried using memory profiler?

Comment: @Adeel please check my comment in added answer what exact problem Now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nikunj instead of making to many timers , make one timer and handle actions  like scrolling in its selector instead for different cells cause for every table view cell timer interval is same ,also you can try do this on willdisplay and invalidate  in willEndDisplaying!(though I don't like this to many timers). Hope it helped!

Comment: Actually, I have a Different number of item in each collection view and want to set auto scroll individually for all from current index to next one so how can I do it with a single timer?

Comment: You say that call **self.setTimer()** from Uitableview cellForRowAt method?

Comment: call setTimer in your controller and in your controller you know which cells has to scroll! simple OR  instead what you can do make a function in controller to calculate if the inside visible table cells collectionview  if need to scroll according to data then do it, i think this is better, hope you get it !

Comment: As per, you say I call **self.setTimer()** from Uitableview cellForRowAt method and also invalidate from there instead of **awakeFromNib** everything is fine when getting the data to display one or more collection view but while clicking on next category that one no any data to display collection view at that time previously seated timer not invalidate so how can i invalidate that

Comment: 1. your timer object and timer selector will be in your VC.
2.in your selector in VC you will manage scroll accordingly like (in willDisplay).
3.add functions to handle cell counter from your VC
4. as the time interval is same for all, so this should not be a problem
meanwhile if i get time i will add code also,